# Deleting all Timers VB.net

Tags: vb.net, timer

I create timers within a class

```
Dim timer As New Timer
                timer.Enabled = True
                timer.Interval = 1000
                timer.Tag = "TimeslipTimer_" & timeslip.id
                AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf GlobalTimerTick
                timer.Start()
```

The problem i have is how can I delete those if I needed?

At the moment I was looking to add timers to a list, similar to below, but i didnt work out

```
dim timers as new list(of Timer)

For Each c As Timer In Timers
                c.Dispose()
                Timers.Remove(c)
            Next
```

Comment: Using Linq `Timers.ForEach(Sub(t) RemoveHandler t.Tick, AddressOf GlobalTimerTick : t.Dispose End Sub) : Timers.Clear()` make sure ypu have `Imports System.Linq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When removing from a list the list must be accessed in reverse order.  Also remember to remove the handler.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents timer As Timer
    Private timers As New List(Of Timer)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        timer = New Timer
        timers.Add(timer)
        timer.Enabled = True
        timer.Interval = 1000
        'timer.Tag = "TimeslipTimer_" & timeslip.id
        AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf GlobalTimerTick
        timer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For x As Integer = timers.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Dim t As Timer = timers(x)
            RemoveHandler t.Tick, AddressOf GlobalTimerTick
            t.Stop()
            t.Dispose()
            timers.RemoveAt(x)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub GlobalTimerTick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Debug.WriteLine("TICK")
    End Sub
End Class
```